# Is there any good replacement for SharePoint Designer?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, add-in, sharepoint-designer

If you've ever used SharePoint Designer, you'll know it's bad. Really bad.

Is there any good replacement for that? Is there any consideration I must take account of if I want to build my own Visual Studio Add-in connector to connect to it?

Anything you know that I should be aware of?

I just hate the slowness and the way SPD (SharePoint Designer) just keeps reformating all my stuff.

Comment: It is slow because it is editing the database, not the file system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the Sharepoint Explorer add-in for Visual Studio which will allow you to browse around sites:

http://blog.thekid.me.uk/archive/2007/10/29/vs-net-developer-add-in-for-sharepoint-available-for-download.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to do. As [Cruiser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285630/is-there-any-good-replacement-for-sharepoint-designer#285669) mentioned, there are options like SharePoint Explorer for exploring a SharePoint farm or site collection. However there are a lot of things that there is no replacement for such as SP Designer workflows, editing page layouts, etc...